# Number of sections in UITableView gets updated but not the tableview datasource array

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am having trouble updating the tableview datasource array.

I want something like this: **If user logged in through registration , he will view 13 rows in tableView**.

If he logged in using Facebook , he would see 10 rows and as a guest he will see 5 rows.

The thing is tableView's rows are updated successfully but not the actions of tableview cells at different indexpaths.

I am doing something like this:

```
 - (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView : (UITableView *) tableView
   {
     // Return the number of sections.
      if( [SharedGlobal SharedSingleton].userBool==TRUE)
      {
       return 5;
      }
     else if([[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"profileArrayForGlobal"] valueForKey:@"UserType"] integerValue]==1)
      {
       return 13;
      }
     else
     {
       return 10;
     }

  }
```

Now for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {

     TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

     if (cell == nil)
     {
       cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                              reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
     }

    if( [SharedGlobal SharedSingleton].userBool==TRUE){

        // do something

    else if([[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"profileArrayForGlobal"] valueForKey:@"UserType"] integerValue]==1)
    {

    //do something              

       if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
       {

        if (!indexPath.row)
        {

          //do something

           if ([expandedSections containsIndex:indexPath.section])
           {

             // do something
           }

           else
            {

             //do something
            }
         }
      else
      {
        // all other rows

      }
   }

else
  {
        cell.accessoryView = nil;


        cell.lblMenuName.text= [lableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        cell.imgMenu.image=[self crop:[UIImage imageNamed: [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]];
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }
 }



else
    {

      cell.lblMenuName.text= [lableArrayOrg objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
      cell.imgMenu.image=[self crop:[UIImage imageNamed: [imageArrayOrg objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]];
      cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
 }

 return cell;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are writing code in wrong method, as you need to show the rows based on differrent condition, change the method from

> - (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView : (UITableView *) tableView

to

> - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section